# How to assign a label to go.layout.Shape(type="line"...)?

Tags: plotly-python

I produce the following figure.
[image: Plot with multiple curves]

The figure has a number of `add_trace` applied to it with `go.Scatter` as arguments.

A list of 4 `go.layout.Shape`, `type="line"`, with fixed `color` attributes, is created and the figure layout is updated with that list:  `fig.update_layout(..., shapes=...)`

The traces have labels assigned to them that we can see to the extreme right.

Is there a way to add labels to assign to the lines as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like your lines to appear in the legend of the figure (https://plot.ly/python/legend/). However, only traces can appear in the legend, not shapes which are a kind of annotation. What you could do is to create the lines using `go.Scatter(..., mode='lines')`, and then they would appear in the legend. You just need to give the starting and end points in `go.Scatter` (see https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/).